# Wortzusammensetzung: Haupt- und Neben-Satz-Handlungen

Tags: grammar, compound

Ich möchte wissen, ob man auf Deutsch die folgende Wortzusammensetzung schreibt:

> Haupt- und Neben-Satz-Handlungen

Ich benutze sie in dem Satz:

> Es gibt (Un-) Gleichzeitigkeit zweiner Haupt- und Neben-Satz-Handlungen

Comment: Was möchtest du zum Ausdruck bringen? Der Satz "Es gibt (Un)Gleichzeitigkeit zweier Haupt-und Neben-Satz-Handlungen" klingt sonderbar.

Comment: @florianb, ich lerne den Temporalsätz und wiederhole meine Notizen..

Comment: danke - ich habe meine Antwort angepasst.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Man schreibt "Haupt- und Nebensatz-Handlungen" oder besser:

> "Haupt- und Nebensatzhandlungen"

Zur Erläuterung: Der erste Einsatz des Bindestrichs bezieht sich auf die [Duden-Regel](http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/bindestrich) §98 (im Link unter Regel 31 zu finden), wonach der *"Bindestrich als Ergänzungszeichen [gesetzt wird], um anzuzeigen, dass ein gleicher Bestandteil von Zusammensetzungen oder Ableitungen eingespart wird"*.

Der zweite Bindestrich ist - meines Erachtens - nicht grundsätzlich untersagt, weshalb ich ihn in der ersten Version auch nicht korrigiert habe. Die diesbezüglichen Regeln finden sich ebenfalls unter dem oben aufgeführten Link, im oberen Abschnitt.

Die den Bindestrich betreffenden Regeln dienen maßgeblich der Verdeutlichung des Satzinhaltes - man darf den Bindestrich einsetzen, um Bestandteile hervorzuheben, um die Übersichtlichkeit zu erhöhen oder zur Vermeidung von Missverständnissen. Das eröffnet, nach meinem Verständnis, zahlreiche subjektive Entscheidungsmöglichkeiten - der diesbezügliche Einsatz eines Bindestrichs mag den Lesefluss beeinträchtigen, aber auch das liegt im Auge des Betrachters.

Nach einer Google-Suche ist die "Hauptsatzhandlung" der "Hauptsatz-Handlung" zahlenmäßig überlegen - es könnte also guter Stil sein ersteres zu verwenden.

Den zweiten Satz würde ich - um der Lesbarkeit willen - in zwei verschiedene Sätze aufteilen, eine Einleitung und eine differenzierendere Erläuterung:

> Es können unterschiedliche Zeitverhältnisse zwischen Haupt- und Nebensatzhandlungen bestehen, welche mit Vor-, Gleich- oder Nachzeitigkeit benannt werden.

Comment: ok, du hast Recht, kein Viertelgeviertstrich zwischen "Neben" und "Satz". Danke! :)

Comment: Die Badezimmertür (wie auch die Badezimmer-Tür) ist beides im Sprachgebrauch zu finden. Eine Zusammenführung von "Nebensatz" und "Handlung" ist unüblich und hat daher noch keinen allgemeingültigen Eingang in den Sprachschatz gefunden, der aus meiner Sicht ein korrigierendes Verhalten legitimiert. Eine Zusammenziehung mit Bindestrich ist daher akzeptabel. Aber vielleicht sollte ich das in der Antwort ausführen.

Comment: Ich hoffe die Aufregung hat sich etwas gelegt - ich habe versucht besser zu erläutern wie ich die Sache sehe. Und die Antwort um die fehlenden Erläuterungen ergänzt.